# adjust zfs settings on freebsd 9

Tags: freebsd, zfs

What's the proper way on FreeBSD 9 to [tune ZFS parameters](http://wiki.freebsd.org/ZFSTuningGuide) such as `vfs.zfs.arc_max` and `vfs.zfs.vdev.cache.size`? I've seen references to `/boot/loader.conf`, `/boot/kernel.conf` and `/etc/sysctl.conf` but I have none of those files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `/boot/loader.conf` is optional file which can be created by user to modify defaults (`/boot/defaults/loader.conf`).
- `/etc/sysctl.conf` is exists in `/usr/src/etc`, but it can be empty file also. it is not critical file too.
- I don't see any mention about `/boot/kernel.conf` in FreeBSD sources and /boot directory.

so, you can do:

- `(echo 'vfs.zfs.arc_max="…"'; echo 'vfs.zfs.vdev.cache.size="…"')>> /boot/loader.conf` (replace … with something useful) and reboot
- place same lines without double quotes into sysctl.conf and restart/reload `sysctl`